# how to show all post with its contents

Tags: posts, categories, archives, youtube

i have "favorite-film-video-songs-super-scene-climax" category and i want to show all of the post with contents(which is youtube video) for every post.

in below link i want to show all post with respective youtube video( like click one particular post it will show youtube).

like this i want to make for this all post.

here missing is all post's youtube video respective.

thanku.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This question involves **wordpress.com use/features**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme determines whether to show excerpts or full content on archive pages (e.g. the cateogry listing), and since you're on WordPress.com, you'll probably have to change themes to one that shows the full content on archive pages. There's a listing here, don't know how complete it is: http://wpbtips.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/full-posts-in-archive-pages/

You might also try putting the HTML code for your video embed in the excerpt box and see if it shows up that way.

Comment: already i embed my youtube video while i post them.but i have Greyzed theme. in ur link i found that that would show only beginning of post.any thanks for ur answer.it really help a lot.is there any chance to change that behavior by customization of my Greyzed theme!??.

Comment: No, I'm afraid on .com you don't have the ability to modify your theme.

Comment: oh.thank u so much again . i had seen ur site . it's worthy and simple.music which is the exception for all language understanding problems.Have a nice day......